# Does Enumerable.Repeat() do a deep copy?

Tags: linq, deep-copy, repeat, enumerable

If I use the following:

```
  var myList = Enumerable.Repeat(myCustomObject, 2);
```

Will the Second element in the list be a deep copy of the first one?

**Note:** myCustomObject can be any Object

**Edit:** Could you also please let me know the potential use of Enumerable.Repeat when dealing with custom objets?

Thanks

Comment: can anyone give me a example where Enumerable.Repeat can come in handy when dealing with custom objects? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "dealing with custom objects" ?

Comment: I just want to know when is Enumerable.Repeat potentially useful

Comment: Mahesh, I have found Enumerable.Repeat(myCustomObject, 0).ToList() to be an effective way of creating a List<T>, where T is an anonymous type I want to insert dynamic content into, for building up little widget classes when I am not quite ready to create a full blown class yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, Enumerable.Repeat actually repeats the exact same reference in the enumerable returned - it is not a copy. (verified via Reflector)

-Oisin

Answer (score 8):

No, `Enumerable.Repeat` will just repeat the reference, it won't make a copy of the object (unless it's a value type of course)